# Как добавить элементы в List<List<string>>?

Tags: c#

Дан текст, его нужно поделить на предложения, а предложения на слова.
Получается, нужно создать List sentences и поместить туда предложения, а затем создать List> words и туда поместить слова, верно? Или предложения должны быть листом листов, а слова просто листом. 
Так вот, как добавить элементы в лист листов.

Помогите пожалуйста, совсем не понимаю как работать со списками.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А ещё говорят, что рекурсия божественна!

Начнём с самой большой вложенности, со слов, которые составляют предложение.

```
var sentence = new List<string>();
sentence.Add("Hello");
sentence.Add("world");
```

Слова соединяются в предложения, из которых и состоит текст:

```
var text = new List<List<string>>();

var sentence = new List<string>();
sentence.Add("Hello");
sentence.Add("world");

text.Add(sentence);
```

Последний код можно переписать и так:

```
var text = new List<List<string>>();
text.Add(new List<string>());

text[text.Count - 1].Add("Hello");
text[text.Count - 1].Add("world");
```

Здесь мы сначала добавляем пустое предложение к тексту, а потом добавляем слова в последнее (`text[text.Count - 1]`) предложение текста.

Если бы у нас был ещё один уровень вложенности, например, картотека, которая состоит из текстов, это выглядело бы так:

```
var directory = new List<List<List<string>>>();

var text = new List<List<string>>();

var sentence = new List<string>();
sentence.Add("Hello");
sentence.Add("world");

text.Add(sentence);

directory.Add(text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант:

```
var sentenseList = inputText
                .Split(new[] { "." }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                .Select(x => x.Split(new[] { "-", " ", "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList())
                .ToList();
```

Где `inputText` это строковая переменная содержащая входной текст для разбора.